# Absolute positioned dropdown menu in scrolling div

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I have a scrollable div of max height around 500px. Inside, are multiple child divs (sections) that have a menu on each of them. The menu are typical dropdowns, something like:

```
.menu ul li{
    position:relative;
    float:none;
    display:none; }
```

The problem I am facing is that when menu opens, it pushes everything down. If I make it position absolute, it messes up for sections that come later down (after scrolling down).

Should I compute offsets by javascript and position them programatically, or can this be resolved via CSS?

One way would be to have the "sections" position absolute. Then I can leverage **position: relative** for the menus to be at the right place in each section. But that is something I can't do due to other reasons.

> JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iamjab/m66sgs5z/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: create a fiddle or snippet mostly this can be done using position absolute

Comment: added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamjab/m66sgs5z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added `position:relative` and `padding-top` for `stackplotwrap` and positioned ul by giving `position:absolute` in the top padding area of `stackplotwrap`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.menu li', function () {
    $(this).find('ul li').css('display', 'block');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.menu li', function () {
    $(this).find('li').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.stackedPlotter {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
.stackplotwrap {
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
.thiswrap {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.menu li {
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu li:hover {
  color: red;
}
.menu li ul li {
  display: none;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stackedPlotter">
  <div class="thiswrap">
    <div class="stackplotwrap">
      <!-- SECTION 1 -->
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Option 1
          <ul>
            <li>Opt 3-1</li>
            <li>Opt 3-2</li>
            <li>Opt3-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Option 2
          <ul>
            <li>Opt 3-1</li>
            <li>Opt 3-2</li>
            <li>Opt3-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Option 3
          <ul>
            <li>Opt 3-1</li>
            <li>Opt 3-2</li>
            <li>Opt3-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stackplotwrap">
      <!-- SECTION 2 -->
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Option 1
          <ul>
            <li>Opt 3-1</li>
            <li>Opt 3-2</li>
            <li>Opt3-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Option 2
          <ul>
            <li>Opt 3-1</li>
            <li>Opt 3-2</li>
            <li>Opt3-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Option 3
          <ul>
            <li>Opt 3-1</li>
            <li>Opt 3-2</li>
            <li>Opt3-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stackplotwrap">
      <!-- SECTION 3 -->
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3
          <ul>
            <li>Opt 3-1</li>
            <li>Opt 3-2</li>
            <li>Opt3-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stackplotwrap">
      <!-- SECTION 4 -->
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3
          <ul>
            <li>Opt 3-1</li>
            <li>Opt 3-2</li>
            <li>Opt3-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stackplotwrap">
      <!-- SECTION 5 -->
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3
          <ul>
            <li>Opt 3-1</li>
            <li>Opt 3-2</li>
            <li>Opt3-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```